# The Jdbc Template Mocking In java

Tags: java, junit, mule, jdbctemplate

I am trying to mock the dao class but I am not able to mock the dao class,  it throws null pointer exception (in the dao class I am using spring jdbc template). I tired to mock the jdbc template also but still it returns jdbc template as null.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ LocationAppDAO.class, BeanPropertyRowMapper.class })
public class CopyOfGeoLocationAppTest {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    public void testJdbcTemplateforDbase() throws Exception {
        // LocationAppDAO locationAppdao= new LocationAppDAO();
        String queryWgs84 = "SELECT * FROM location_wgs84 where latitude=" + 0
                + " AND longitude=" + 0;
        LocationAppDAO locationAppDaoMock= EasyMock.createMock(LocationAppDAO.class);
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateMock = EasyMock.createMock(JdbcTemplate.class);
        BeanPropertyRowMapper<Location_wgs84> beanPropertyRowMapperMock = EasyMock
                .createMock(BeanPropertyRowMapper.class);

        EasyMock.replay(beanPropertyRowMapperMock);
        // mocking location
        Location_wgs84 location_wgs84mock = EasyMock
                .createMock(Location_wgs84.class);
        location_wgs84mock.setLatitude(0);
        location_wgs84mock.setLongitude(0);
        EasyMock.replay(location_wgs84mock);
        PowerMock.expectNew(BeanPropertyRowMapper.class).andReturn(
                beanPropertyRowMapperMock);
        PowerMock.replayAll();
        ArrayList<Location_wgs84> arrayList = new ArrayList<Location_wgs84>();
        Location_wgs84 location1 = new Location_wgs84();
        location1.setLatitude(1);
        location1.setLongitude(1);
        arrayList.add(location1);
        Location_wgs84 location2 = new Location_wgs84();
        location2.setLatitude(2);
        location2.setLongitude(2);
        arrayList.add(location2);
        Location_wgs84 location3 = new Location_wgs84();
        location3.setLatitude(3);
        location3.setLongitude(3);
        arrayList.add(location3);
        EasyMock.expect(
                jdbcTemplateMock.query(queryWgs84, beanPropertyRowMapperMock))
                .andStubAnswer(new IAnswer<List<Location_wgs84>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<Location_wgs84> answer() throws Throwable {
                        return arrayList;
                    };
                });
        EasyMock.replay(jdbcTemplateMock);
        EasyMock.expect(
                locationAppDaoMock.location_wgs84Query(0,0))
                .andStubAnswer(new IAnswer<List<Location_wgs84>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<Location_wgs84> answer() throws Throwable {
                        return arrayList;
                    };
                });
        EasyMock.replay(locationAppDaoMock);
        LocationAppDAO locationAppdao= new LocationAppDAO();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(locationAppdao, "jdbcTemplate", jdbcTemplateMock);
        List<Location_wgs84> arrayListResult = locationAppdao.location_wgs84Query(0, 0);
        assertEquals(3.0, arrayListResult.get(2).getLatitude(), 0);
        EasyMock.verify(jdbcTemplateMock);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about providing a datasource that returns the data you need ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mocking libraries, I often use [H2 database](http://h2database.com/). I set up an in memory database with a DDL that allows me to verify that my application is making the right changes to the underlying tables and/or stored procedures, without having to lock my tests to the specifics of the database access library.

All you need to do is provide a connection string when running tests, similar to the one below.  It will create the database and run the DDL any time a connection is made.

```
jdbc:h2:mem:example_database;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:db/my-example-database.ddl'
```